# Firefox OS OAuth 2.0 procedure

Tags: api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, firefox-os

I'm currently building an app in javascript for the new Firefox OS and am stuck on how to implement Google Drive API via OAuth v2. The app is probably on

```
http://localhost and urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

, therefore I have the setup Client ID for installed applications as well as Client ID for Drive SDK. Since it is in the app, I have embedded the browser(iframe) for OAuth wherein the user will grant the application access and the refresh_token will be saved by app and the user get redirected to app. There should be no popup and this should be contained within the app.

So how can I accomplish this/what is the best way of doing this as I don't have access to localhost and which method would be the best(e.g. jsclient, http request,...)?

This app is just client based(no server-side). Also another question, can the User enter its username and password in app that we sent to google for authorization?

Comment: Don't ask vague and multiple questions in a single entry.

Comment: This is a whole new OS that is therefore fairly different, so how can I exactly know how to do this? The main question is how can I do auth on client-side without having access to localhost(default redirect).

Answer (score 2):

well you can refer to [gaia calendar app](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/), which use the google calendar caldev API.

EDIT: read recent discussion about [OAuth flow for packaged Open Web Apps](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mozilla.dev.gaia/L8XMkH5V0xs) in gaia-dev group

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/LDSorg/fxos-oauth2-jquery-demo for an example of the Implicit Grant (browser-only, no server) strategy.

manifest.json:

```
{ "name": "OAuth2 jQuery Demo"
, "description": "Login using OAuth2 / OAuth3 with jQuery"
, "version": "1.0"
, "type": "privileged"
, "launch_path": "/index.html"
, "developer": {
    "name": "John Doe"
  , "url": "https://johndoe.com"
  }
, "redirects": {
    "from": "http://should-be-a-fake-domain.com"
  , "to": "/oauth-close.html"
  }
}
```

Note:

Must be a privileged app:

```
"type": "privileged"
```

And the redirects must be in place:

```
"redirects": {
  "from": "http://use-a-fake-domain.com/my-redirect"
, "to": "/oauth-close.html"
}
```

Then you set your `redirect_uri` to `http://use-a-fake-domain.com`. You could, of course, use your own domain - and you might need to if you can't add the fake domain to the domain whitelist of the provider you're using - I just like using a fake domain because it's a visual queue to me.

Answer (score 0):

i also have same question.Do you have a better solution for google auth in firefox os?

[Firefox OS privileged app: Permission denied to access property 'document' of new window object created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531510/firefox-os-privilleged-app-permission-denied-to-access-property-document-of-ne)